# the count time is too long

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT  
sql_no_cache   
COUNT(p.id)   
FROM shop_products p    
LEFT OUTER JOIN shop_currency currency ON (p.currencyId=currency.id)   
INNER JOIN shop_l2p l2p2 FORCE INDEX(show2) ON (p.id=l2p2.pid and l2p2.status>0)   
INNER JOIN shop_labels l2 ON (l2p2.lid=l2.id and l2.type=2 and l2.status=1)   
LEFT JOIN shop_l2p l2p3 ON (p.id=l2p3.pid and l2p3.status=1)   
LEFT JOIN shop_labels l3 ON (l2p3.lid=l3.id and l3.type=3 and l3.status=1)   
WHERE 
CONCAT(p.label,l3.label,l2.label,p.stockCode) LIKE '%moda%'  
AND p.status='1'  A
ND p.stockAmount<>0  
AND p.isOption=0 
limit 1;

+-------------+
| COUNT(p.id) |
+-------------+
|        6669 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (3.91 sec)
```

with a different idea?

Comment: What indexes do you have on those tables? What's the execution plan of the query?

Comment: Do you have indexes created? `LIKE '%moda%' ` if search string contains `%` in the front index will not work

Comment: I think you should also present where you have index, maybe how many records you have and be more explicative

Comment: write `EXPLAIN` before `SELECT` and analyze in phpmyadmin.... please provide your table structure

Comment: Regardless of the indexes on the table you are going to run into problems with the filter starting CONCAT(... I would be tempted to run the query with the other restrictions first and build the concat as a field then query the result

Answer (score 1):

Loose the concat. Put the where on the different fields.

```
WHERE
  ( p.label LIKE '%moda%' or
    l3.label LIKE '%moda%' or
    l2.label LIKE '%moda%' or
    p.stockCode LIKE '%moda%')
  AND ....
```

For these labels you might be better off using fulltext indexes, although they search in a somewhat different way. This can be and advantage or a disadvantage. The advantage is that you can get a score per result and not only if they match or not.

Comment: Good call.  `CONCAT` prevents efficient index use.

Comment: that's not exactly the same as your solution wouldn't match where 'moda' runs over concatenation boundaries, e.g. when p.label = 'amo' and l3.label = 'd' and l2.label = 'aa'. The question is whether this behavior is desired, as it seems pretty weird anyway.

Comment: I figured that it's not desired, because you search in different labels and it wouldn't make sense to search over concatenated boundaries. But you're right, I should have mentioned that my implementation could lead to different results.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this performance problem is to run the analyzer on the query (or during the query) and it will pinpoint the clause causing the problem.

Comment: hi;How do I get the count faster than a structure with multi joinli

Answer (score 0):

try these changes:

```
SELECT  
sql_no_cache   
COUNT(p.id)   
FROM shop_products p    
INNER JOIN shop_l2p l2p2 FORCE INDEX(show2) ON (p.id=l2p2.pid and l2p2.status>0)   
INNER JOIN shop_labels l2 ON (l2p2.lid=l2.id and l2.type=2 and l2.status=1)   
LEFT JOIN shop_l2p l2p3 ON (p.id=l2p3.pid and l2p3.status=1)   
LEFT JOIN shop_labels l3 ON (l2p3.lid=l3.id and l3.type=3 and l3.status=1)   
WHERE 
p.status='1'  and
AND p.stockAmount<>0  
AND p.isOption=0 
(p.label like '%moda%'
or l3.label like '%moda%'
or l2.label like '%moda%'
or p.stockCode like '%moda%')
limit 1;
```

reasons:

- left join to shop_currency isnt used.
- CONCAT forces all thos fields to contat with no need to.
- If you filter out using the fastest fields first, it wont need to check the strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
1   SIMPLE  p   ref     PRIMARY,productAdmin,isOption,show,status,stockAmo...   status  1   const   40018   Using where
1   SIMPLE  l2p3    ref     lid,show2,pid,l2p_products  show2   5   ideashopfix.p.id,const  2   Using where
1   SIMPLE  l3  eq_ref  PRIMARY,show,type,typeStatus,status     PRIMARY     4   ideashopfix.l2p3.lid    1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  l2p2    ref     show2   show2   4   ideashopfix.p.id    3   Using where
1   SIMPLE  l2  eq_ref  PRIMARY,show,type,typeStatus,status     PRIMARY     4   ideashopfix.l2p2.lid    1   Using where
```

concat to like changed, time too long (4.07 sec)